# defining location of files at deployment time

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, dll, c#-3.0

I have an app that has search functionality.  The search algorithm is compiled to a separate dll.  In the C# code for the search algorithm, I am using strings held in a settings file to point to the directory where the search index resides.  But once the search code is compiled, the settings file is somehow incorporated in the dll. I want to have multiple versions of this code running on my server with each pointing to a different location for the index. And I want the operator to change a file to have each version point to something else as they find necessary.  Both config files and settings files end up getting incorporated in the dll.  How do I then accomplish this? What is the right industry standard way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's strange that the settings file is compiled... are you sure about that? Setting, config and resx files should be copied to the output directory, it's even a property you can modify on solution explorer. Then you should get it's values by doing

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("YourKey")
```

But I think this won't know about user changes until app is restarted. If you want settings to be dynamic you should either store them on a database, or on a file that you open, read and close every time you need it.

Hope this helped!

Comment: I can restart the app. That is not a problem. Either it is compiled or I don't know where it puts the file. Where would it be output to? Thanks!

Comment: The output file "should" be the bin folder, when compiling.

Comment: I didd some more digging and rephrased the whole question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762938/moving-the-config-files-for-a-dll-to-the-app-that-calls-the-dll. Thanks for your input. You helped me in the right direction.