# How can i read web.config from DLL using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

suppose i have a project named dummyCode.sln, now when i compile the project i would get a dll named dummyCode.dll.

How can i read this DLL using c# and get the information of my web.config

**for example if i have a web.config like this**

```
<configuration>
 <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="employeeDB" value="Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=employee;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=userid;Password=password;"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

then i want to read al the values found inside the appsettings attribute, how can i do it, is it possible to do?

Comment: what you mean by _read the Dll_ ? Load dll to app domain and then read metadata ?

Comment: A DLL is a class library - class libraries don't have their own config file, they use the config file of the application that is referencing them.

Answer (score 1):

This Dll will be used in some Exe or a Website. You need to added these config entries to that Exe's or Website's config file.

app.Config (for Exe) and web.config (for Website)

Once done, you can read these using:

```
string theValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KeyName"];
```

(Namespace: `System.Configuration`)

Bonus, you can create methods to read different info:

Example: `Int`

```
public static int GetIntConfiguration(string keyName)
{
    string value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[keyName] ?? "0";
    int theValue = 0;
    if (int.TryParse(value, out theValue))
    {
       return theValue;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

So a -1, tell you that there is an invalid value in config.

Similarly, you can create methods for other types.

**EDIT: based on your comment**,
If you need to open a custom config:

```
System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("dllPath.dll");

string value = config.AppSettings.Settings["key"].Value;
```

If it's a web.config, you can change the first line to:

```
System.Configuration.Configuration configWeb = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("");
```

Comment: ok, when i compile my solution file, i will get a dll, which would have all the files along woth web.config, right? i want to read the dll and get the web.config information. i dont want to know the ways to read web.config from the application. i want ways to read the dll and the information of the web.config file inside the dll

Comment: Edited the post for extra details.

Comment: @LijinDurairaj DLLs don't have config files. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments already, compiled DLLs of class library projects don't have their own `.config` file. If you made an `app.config` or `web.config` within that project, it is not included as part of what gets compiled into the DLL. The DLL only contains .NET code.

It wouldn't make any logical sense to do so - the settings files are meant to be per application, not per project. Otherwise they could conflict with each other, and/or not be adjustable to suit the application where the library is included.

P.S. This has been dealt with before on SO, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762938/moving-the-config-files-for-a-dll-to-the-app-that-calls-the-dll/16867319) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594298/c-sharp-dll-config-file) (and possibly elsewhere). There are a couple of suggestions of how you *could* achieve your aim, but also plenty of similar discussion about why it's not a very good idea.